# A gear icon appeared in my Xcode app icon project and I cannot run it anymore

Tags: ios, xcode, spring, xcode7

I've added a framework and a library (spring) to perform animations with buttons, etc.
Now instead of one app icon to launch, in x-code, I got three, and can launch them all except the main one. The main app icon it's now a gear, and I cannot run it because x-code don't let me select any device to launch it. I can only select my mac, as you can see in image...

[image]

There is also another thing. The yu.app in product folder turns to red only when I'm in the main app. When I choose spring it turns black again. Anybody know how to fix this issue?

[image]

[image]

Comment: try to add new scheme after deleting existing one.

Comment: it's working, now I can launch but it throws me an error : 
error: failed to remove /Users/Alfro/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/yuApp-drboxbjcbyrksfcitdapmkcvpwxw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/yuApp.app/Info.plist: “Info.plist” couldn’t be removed.

Comment: do I need to remove it manually?

Comment: Thank you @MOHAMMADISHAQ I managed to fix this issue thanks to your help, if you post it I will approve your answer.

Comment: You welcome, sorry i was away so didn't replied you for error .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do following

1 - Navigate to manage scheme

2 - Remove older scheme

3 - Create new scheme

For removing files of older scheme you need to remove derived data.

From XCode  Window  >  Projects  >  Select Your Project  >  delete derived data

Comment: Removing an old scheme and creating a new one worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

All the answers here suggest a way which may work but not the proper solution.

Just select your scheme, go to **Edit Scheme**. Go to **Run**. In **Executable** dropdown select the correct app and it will start working. No need to create new scheme or delete any scheme.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to Manage Schemes add a new scheme for your app target yuApp and remove any outdated schemes.